# Skyrim: remove/complete bugged misc quests

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have 2 quests filed under the Miscellaneous category of my journal in Skyrim (*talking to Greta about going back to the Temple of Divines* and *Bring a dragon scale and a dragon bone to Esbern*) that I cannot complete. I tried a lot of things to fix them but I could not succeed.
First I enabled the tracking to get a hint of where to continue the quests, I tried the `CompleteAllObjectives` command, `ShowQuestStages` command, `SetStage`, `CompleteQuest`... And then I tried `ShowQuestTargets`.
The `sqt` command shows the targets of all currently started quests, and also the ID of the next doors leading to these targets. By issuing consecutive `sqt` and `Player.MoveTo <DoorID>`, I tracked down all of the targets shown by `sqt`, and guess what: the doors I took led me to places where I could find all of the targets of my **other** quests. Just not these specific two misc quests. Also, when I open the journal, the Miscellaneous section displays 6 objectives, for which I can open the map and get a hint of the location, **except** these two quests again, for which the the key to open the map is greyed-out. Additionally, the `sqs` command for the "Speak to Greta" quest shows 5 stages, and the 3rd and the 4th of them are shown not completed (0-state) while the 5th is actually completed (1-state). For the "Esbern" quest, it shows 2 stages which are both completed...

Any ideas ? :c

Comment: Have you tried `ResetQuest <QuestID>`?

Comment: ...actually it doesn't work. It did reset the quest, so I did it again, and the quest entry is still in my journal. :/